# How to have Access send automatic notifications via Outlook

Tags: database, email, ms-access, outlook

I designed a simple Access database and a form to save data in it. My question is: When someone opens the form and fills it, once they click on "save" button I want some people (admins) get a notification email to their inbox. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
oMail.Body = "Body of the email"
oMail.Subject = "The subject of the email"
oMail.To = "Someone@somewhere.com"
oMail.Send
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
```

You can also add attachements if you wish. And in the body, you can include data that was on your form bu using

```
Forms!frm_yourformname!CustomerName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help:) Although it took days, I finally figured it out.

Comment: @user3127229 Glad to here you fixed it. If you want, post what you did to fix it for future reference. Theres a big chance that someone with the same problem will stumble upon this post in the future.